# Since CKEditor 4.1, execCommand is not working without toolbar plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Initially I tested without toolbar, inline:
[4.0](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/3/)[W], [4.1](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/2/)[N], [4.2](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/5/)[N], [4.3](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/2/)[N] (W = Works; N = not working).

[With toolbar @ 4.3, inline](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/6/): Works.

[Without toolbar, standard](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DACxJ/7/): Not working.

Basically, since 4.1 version there have been some changes, that affect external buttons. That causes for something like this...

```
<a href="#bold" data-command="bold">Bold</a>

$('[data-command]').on({
    click : function(e)
    {
        var command = $(this).data('command');

        command = editor.execCommand(command);

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

..to not work.

I've managed to debug, that the button state appears to be "inactive" at all times. I did attempt a `getCommand()`, `.enable()` and only then `.exec()` combination, but, no changes.

I've currently overcome the issue by using `sharedspace` plugin and moving the `toolbar` into a hidden element.

What is the 4.3 way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [Advanced Content Filter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) as since CKEditor 4.1 contents, commands and UI have been tied up together.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( editable , {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    // This is what got to be added
    extraAllowedContent: 'strong em u'
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/zBm3d/)

Comment: Nice, didn't catch it in the changelog though.